# Can not login from os-commerce admin panel

Tags: php, oscommerce

Hi i have installed the oscommerce 2.3.1 which has installed succesfully but problem is i can not login from admin when im entering user name and pwd it says `error invalid administrator login attempt`but front end works fine .im just geting little confusion why that error has caused.

am using my local server xammp.

Any advice, patronising or otherwise, much appreciated.

Comment: SO is about programming, you are asking support for a program. I'd suggest you ask your question at the OSCommerce forum.

Comment: as far as I remember OSCommerce relies on register_globals, so turn them on and try again.

Comment: i got a result.....thanks @Darhazer

Answer (score 0):

Bharath, **If it IS a register_globals issue**, by default OSC requires them to be on, but your webhost might have them off, download and follow the instructions (it's very simple -- anybody can follow these instructions) for the [Registers Globals Patch PHP4.](http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,2957/category,all/search,Register+Globals+Patch+Files) or the [Register Globals Patch Files for php5.](http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,2957/category,5/search,Register+Globals).

If it's not a thing with register_globals, you need to clear administrator table and the oscommerce software will offer to create the account, only this way it will work.

If this is not clear, try emptying the action recorder and administrator table and editing the .htaccess table, deleting the OSC password table and then shut down all browsers.

Restart the browser(s) and try again.  I'm guessing that this will solve the issue, and you can ignore what I wrote below.

Normally, the files for password validation are not changed. However, if you feel your files are, consider replacing them with new files from the **original download**.  It is a simple task to replace the files with the originals. Just make sure you use files from the same version your shop is currently running on and MAKE A BACKUP of all files before changing anything.

If this still fails, or if you're not understanding, and you think it might be a password issue, follow this link: http://www.theukwaltons.co.uk/product_info.php/forgotten-admin-password-p-51?osCsid=aaeb6433faf5e66b54d5b7ce1ad9d93d

If you still can't find help, just let me know and I'll fix it for you.

Hope this helps.